# logstash: Running update via RPM stepped on my logstash.yml

Tags: logstash

Using RPM to update from logstash 5.4.1 to 5.6.4

Everything went great, but the command:

```
yum localinstall logstash-5.6.4.rpm
```

resulted in my /etc/logstash/logstash.yml getting overwritten by the config in the rpm.

I don't recall seeing an RPM do that before.

Would the RPM have made a backup to some magic place of the prior yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an RPM spec file marks the file as a configuration, it will either create a backup with the extension **.rpmsave** or it will leave the file on disk alone and write the file from the package as **filename.rpmnew**.

In your case, if you don't have **filename.rpmsave** file in the same path, their RPM does not mark it as a config. You can verify this with `rpm -qc logstash`. Maybe this is by design, but I would consider filing a bug upstream.

For more information, see this page on the resulting behavior under various conditions.

http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jw35/docs/rpm_config.html